# How to make my FireTV app voice controllable via Alexa?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-fire-tv

I would like to make my FireTV app respond to to a command similar to **"alexa open google.com in Firefox"**. Skimming through the alexa documentation I'm not sure if this is doable without creating a huge overhead with user & device authentication (custom skill). Obviously alexa is designed to be device independent, this is what makes everything tricky.

So how do I do this?
Here's my ideas so far:

*Approach 1:* 
Create an AWS hosted application where the user has to register his app. Benefit would be that i can make the user say something like **"view google.com in firefox on my living room firetv"**. Then i would have to send a push notification to the living room firetv, which my app is registered for. (Huge overhead for a simple task).

*Approach 2:*
I could skip device independency and just try to implement voice controllability in my app (meaning the user would have to open firefox and then say **"view google.com"**. Google offers an API for this, but after some research I'm not sure amazon does, so this could be a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Voice-enabling Your App and Content](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/voice-enable-your-app-and-content.html). It doesn't address the scenario you described above, but it explains what voice capabilities are available in Fire TV apps, and how to implement them.